# How to play a .pls file in iOS?

Tags: ios

I am trying to develop a radio application for iOS. I want to play the .pls files. I tried using AVPlayer but to no success. I retreived the URL from .pls. That also does not run. The stream however runs if I open the .pls file using the UIWebView.

Is there anything I can do to play it natively rather than using webview?

```
PLS link : http://66.23.234.242:8012/listen.pls
```

Answer (score 1):

Check out this link  https://discussions.apple.com/thread/1924391?start=0&tstart=0

PLS is a computer file format that stores multimedia playlists. It is a more expressive format than basic M3U, as it can store (cache) information on the song title and length — extended M3U supports this, too. With PLS version 2, playlists also include a PLS version declaration.

To play these files you need a media player on your operating system that is able to play these files. One of these media players is iTunes.
"Copied from the above mentioned link"

Comment: The pls file works when i open from a webview. My problem is even after i get the link from pls file it doesn't play.Any idea why?

Answer (score 1):

using `MPMoviePlayer` we can play .pls file and you have to hide that `MPMoviePlayer`, it look like a audio player and add subview to your view.

```
moviePlayer = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:[NSURL URLWithString: @"your .pls link"]];
[moviePlayer.moviePlayer prepareToPlay];
moviePlayer.view.hidden = YES;
[self.view addSubview:moviePlayer.view];
```

//for play:

```
[moviePlayer.moviePlayer play];
```

//for pause:

```
[moviePlayer.moviePlayer stop];
```